# How to convert dataframe column pairs to individual dictionary mappings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

How to convert data frame values into dictionary

```
D_ID    Designation  G_Code G

1       Developer       1   M
1       Developer       2   F
1       Developer       1   M
2       Testing         1   M
2       Testing         1   M
2       Testing         2   F
```

Expected out

d1 = {1: "Developer", 2: "Testing"}

d2 = {1: "M", 2: "F"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what columns need to be paired in advance, you create a pairs dict and iterate over it quite neatly:

```
pairs = {'D_ID': 'Designation', 'G_Code': 'G'}
[df.set_index(k)[v].to_dict() for k, v in pairs.items()]
# [{1: 'Developer', 2: 'Testing'}, {1: 'M', 2: 'F'}]
```

---

If you have just two pairs, you can assign the result to "d1" and "d2":

```
d1, d2 = (df.set_index(k)[v].to_dict() for k, v in pairs.items())
d1
# {1: 'Developer', 2: 'Testing'}
d2
# {1: 'M', 2: 'F'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a data frame to a dictionary using the function `to_dict` with the parameter `orient='split'`.

```
df[['D_ID', 'Designation']].to_dict('split')
```

Output:

```
{'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 'columns': ['D_ID', 'Designation'],
 'data': [[1, 'Developer'],
  [1, 'Developer'],
  [1, 'Developer'],
  [2, 'Testing'],
  [2, 'Testing'],
  [2, 'Testing']]}
```

Then you can select `'data'` from the resulted dictionary and convert it to another dictionary using the function `dict`.

```
dct = {'D_ID': 'Designation', 'G_Code': 'G'}
[dict(df[[k, v]].to_dict('split')['data']) for k, v in dct.items()]
```

Output:

```
[{1: 'Developer', 2: 'Testing'}, {1: 'M', 2: 'F'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to accepted answer you can consider to use `groupby`, `first` and finally `to_dict`.

```py
d1 = df.groupby("D_ID")["Designation"].first().to_dict()
d2 = df.groupby("G_Code")["G"].first().to_dict()
```

Or eventually using pairs as suggested by @cs95

```py
pairs = {'D_ID': 'Designation', 'G_Code': 'G'}
d1, d2 = (df.groupby(k)[v].first().to_dict() for k, v in pairs.items())
```

## Timing

### @cs95

```py
%%timeit
pairs = {'D_ID': 'Designation', 'G_Code': 'G'}
d1, d2 = (df.set_index(k)[v].to_dict() for k, v in pairs.items())

1.06 ms ± 23.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

### groupby

```py
%%timeit -n 100
d1 = df.groupby("D_ID")["Designation"].first().to_dict()
d2 = df.groupby("G_Code")["G"].first().to_dict()

1.29 ms ± 15.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

### `groupby` + pairs

```py
%%timeit -n 100
pairs = {'D_ID': 'Designation', 'G_Code': 'G'}
d1, d2 = (df.groupby(k)[v].first().to_dict() for k, v in pairs.items())

1.4 ms ± 24.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

## Conclusion

It looks like in this example @cs95 solution is the clear winner. But I'd like to know which one are the timing for your real case example.